# Embed the main window of a qt/C++ application in a wpf/mvvm application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, qt, winapi

I need to embed a qt/c++ application in a wpf mvvm application. The window of this qt/C++ has to be integrated in a wpf page displayed in a tab page.

The page Control is the following :

```
<page x:Class="Wpf_HostExe.Page1"
    xmlns:="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Page1"
    Loaded="OnLoaded">
    <Grid>
        <Border x:Name="HostUi" Background="White"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I start the app to be hosted with the instructions below :

```
public static Process StartProcess()
{
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\ChildApp\\";
    processStartInfo.fileName = "ChildApp.exe";
    processStartInfo.Arguments = "";

    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processStartInfo);
    proc.WaitForInputIdle();

    return proc;
}
```

The external window is reparented by the following instructions :

```
public class ApplicationHost : HwndHost
{
    private const uint LBS_NOTIFY = 0x00000001;
    private const uint WS_BORDER = 0x00800000;
    private const int SWP_NO_ACTIVATE = 0x0010;
    private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    private const int WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000;
    private const int WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000;
    private const uint WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll"), SetLastError = true]
    private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);

    public IntPtr ApplicationHandle { get; set; }
    ...
    protected override HandleRef BuildWindowCore (HandleRef hwndParent)
    {
        var result = new HandleRef(this, ApplicationHandle);
        if (ApplicationHandle.ToInt32() == 0)
        {
            return result;
        }

        var oldParent = SetParent(ApplicationHandle, hwndParent.Handle);

        var styles = GetWindowLong(ApplicationHandle, GWL_STYLE);
        styles |= WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | LBS_NOTIFY;
        styles &= ~WS_CAPTION;
        SetWindowLong32(ApplicationHandle, GWL_STYLE, styles);

        return result;
    }
    ...
}
```

I also tried the following version :

```
    ...
    protected override HandleRef BuildWindowCore (HandleRef hwndParent)
    {
        SetParent(ApplicationHandle, hwndParent.Handle);

        int style = GetWindowLong(ApplicationHandle, GWL_STYLE);
        style = style & ~WS_CAPTION & ~WS_THICKFRAME;
        SetWindowLong(ApplicationHandle, GWL_STYLE, style);
    }
    ...
```

The process of the app to be hosted start without problem but the SetParent doesn't seem to work and I get the following message while the method BuildWindowCore has been passed whatever the way the setParent is done :

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occured in PresentationFramework.dll"
Additional Information : Hosted HWND must be a child window of the specified parent. "
```

I tried a lot of things found on stackoverflow but I still have this same InvalidOperationException thrown and have no clue on how to fix that.

Could you please help me ?

Regards,

Comment: Embedding a window from one process as a child of a window in another process is something that, essentially, you can't expect to succeed. It needs plentiful cooperation from both parties, and a deep understanding of win32. You have essentially zero prospect of success combining Qt and WPF in this way. Find another solution.

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) Here is the important take-away: *"If you create a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned relationship, the consequences can be very difficult to manage. And **they become near-impossible to manage if one or both of the windows involved is unaware that it is participating in a cross-process window tree**."* Neither WPF nor Qt is prepared for this stunt.

Answer (score -1):

I presume that you have the source to the Qt application. In that code, you must create a function that will `render()` the widget on a `QImage`. Call that function from WPF, and copy the image from QImage's `data()` to a [`WriteableBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap?view=netframework-4.8), and show that using a control. You can also forward the mouse and keyboard clicks in the opposite direction, and have a function that then synthesizes the `QEvent`s to interact with the widget.